# SwiftUI: Adding Preferences menu to AppView

Tags: macos, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI App. I can add menus to the app, that's quite simple. It adds an extra menu onto the menubar. But how do I add an About screen, a Preferences screen or even anything to the existing File menu?

Here is my code:

```
@main
struct MyApp: App
{
    var body: some Scene
    {
        WindowGroup
        {
             ContentView()
        }
        .commands 
        {
            CommandMenu("My menu") 
            {
                Button("Item 1") 
                {
                   print ("item 1")
                }
   
                Button("Preferences...") 
                {
                    preferencesWindowController.show()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm also using the [Preferences](https://github.com/sindresorhus/Preferences) package from sindresorhus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- To add a Preferences... menu item you add a `Settings` view after your WindowGroup

```
     WindowGroup {
         ContentView()
     }
      
     Settings {
         MyCustomSettingsView()
     }
```

- An About screen is already included in your macOS app but you can customise it by adding a Rich Text file to your project named "Credits.rtf"
- To add anything to an existing menu you use a `CommandGroup`, the below examples adds a new menu item after "New Window" in the File menu

```
    CommandGroup(after: .newItem, addition: {
        Button { someAction() } label: { Text("Some Action" }
    })
```